# How to convert a String in an Array for AroraDB 5.7.12?

Tags: mysql, arrays, amazon-aurora

I know that I can use JSON_ARRAYAGG function for the version from MySQL 5.7.22 to earn an array of grouped object, but I use an old version for my job. Someone knows how can I use a similar function like JSON_ARRAYAGG for AroraDB 5.7.12? Because I need to group values in an array of objects. 
    For example, I've used GROUP_CONCAT(), but the result is a string of object separated for commas ',' and I need that result will be a List.
    Something like that, for example:

```
This is my table:
+-----------------+---------------+
| State           | City          |
+-----------------+---------------+
| Capital Region  | Canberra      |
| New South Wales | Sydney        |
| New South Wales | Newcastle     |
| New South Wales | Central Coast |
| New South Wales | Wollongong    |
| Queensland      | Brisbane      |
| Queensland      | Gold Coast    |
| Queensland      | Townsville    |
| Queensland      | Cairns        |
| South Australia | Adelaide      |
| Tasmania        | Hobart        |
| Victoria        | Melbourne     |
| Victoria        | Geelong       |
| West Australia  | Perth         |
+-----------------+---------------+

And I want the next result:
+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| State           | Cities                                                 |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Capital Region  | ["Canberra"]                                           |
| New South Wales | ["Sydney", "Newcastle", "Central Coast", "Wollongong"] |
| Queensland      | ["Brisbane", "Gold Coast", "Townsville", "Cairns"]     |
| South Australia | ["Adelaide"]                                           |
| Tasmania        | ["Hobart"]                                             |
| Victoria        | ["Melbourne", "Geelong"]                               |
| West Australia  | ["Perth"]                                              |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------+

So, is there a MySQL function to this? 
Thanks for your attention!
```

Answer (score 5):

Combining `GROUP_CONCAT` with `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"',city,'"')),']') AS JSON) AS cities
FROM tab
GROUP BY State;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=705e260e9c7598991fb0dbc7f9b52ebf)**

Answer (score 0):

For those using MySql on Aurora - Aurora 2.10.1 clusters support JSON_ARRAYAGG.